# Row to fix stop code compile just before the end?

Tags: c, macos, compilation

sorry for my spoken mode, I haven't practiced English for a while.

I have some trouble with my C code, the code stops compile just before the end like the code end in this step, I have saved and search for wrongs but I can't find it, I'm using a MacBook Air M1 and would like know if the problem can be the hardware or how can I fix this.

Thank you by the way!

The code (stops in the "Fim fatorial" terminal:user@machine output %):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    // Inicio 1)
    printf("\n----------------------- Inicio leitura de inteiro ---------------------\n");
    int num;

    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    printf("O numero digitado é %i", num);
    printf("\n----------------------- Fim leitura de inteiro ----------------------\n");
    // Fim 1)


    // Inicio 2)
    printf("\n----------------------- Inicio soma ----------------------\n");
    int numUm;
    int numDois;

    printf("Digite um numero inteiro para a soma: ");
    scanf("%i", &numUm);
    printf("Digite um segundo numero inteiro para a soma: ");
    scanf("%i", &numDois);

    int soma = numUm + numDois;

    printf("A soma dos numero é igual a %i", soma);
    printf("\n----------------------- Fim soma ----------------------\n");
    // Fim 2)


    // Inicio 3)
    printf("\n----------------------- Inicio calculo de area ----------------------\n");
    float raio;

    printf("Digite o raio: ");
    scanf("%f", &raio);

    float area = ((raio * raio) * 3.1416);

    printf("Considerando pi = 3,1416, a area da circunferência é %.2f", area);
    printf("\n----------------------- Fim calculo de area ----------------------\n");
    // Fim 3)


    // Inicio 4)
    printf("\n-------------------- Inicio conversor de temperatura ------------------\n");
    float celsius;

    printf("Digite a temperatura em Cº: ");
    scanf("%f", &celsius);

    float fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9/5) + 32);

    printf("%.2fº celsius é equivalente a %.2f fahrenheits", celsius, fahrenheit);
    printf("\n--------------------- Fim conversor de temperatura -------------------\n");
    // Fim 4)


    // Inicio 5)
    printf("\n-------------------- Inicio positivo, negativo, 0 --------------------\n");
    int numTres;

    printf("Digite um número inteiro: ");
    scanf("%i", &numTres);

    if (numTres > 0) {
        printf("O numero %i é positivo.", numTres);
    }
    
    else if (numTres < 0) {
        printf("O numero %i é negativo", numTres);
    }
    
    else if (numTres == 0) {
        printf("O numero é igual a 0");
    }
    printf("\n---------------------- Fim positivo, negativo, 0 ----------------------\n");
    // Fim 5)


    // Inicio 6)
    char nomeoperacao[20], simbolo = ' ';
    int escolha;
    float numQuatro, numCinco, intermediaria;

    printf("\n------------------------ Operação matemática ----------------------------");
    printf("\n 1- soma \n 2- subtração \n 3- multiplicação \n 4- Divisão\n");
    printf("Opção desejada: ");
    scanf("%i", &escolha);

    printf("\nDigite um número para operação: ");
    scanf("%f", &numQuatro);
    printf("\nDigite um segundo número para operação: ");
    scanf("%f", &numCinco);

    if (escolha == 1) {
        intermediaria = (numQuatro + numCinco);
        simbolo = '+';
        strcpy(nomeoperacao, "soma");
    }

    else if (escolha == 2) {
        intermediaria = (numQuatro - numCinco);
        simbolo = '-';
        strcpy(nomeoperacao, "subtração");
    }
    
    else if (escolha == 3) {
        intermediaria = (numQuatro * numCinco);
        simbolo = '*';
        strcpy(nomeoperacao, "multiplicação");    
    }

    else if (escolha == 4) {
        intermediaria = (numQuatro / numCinco);
        simbolo = '/';
        strcpy(nomeoperacao, "divisão");    
    }

    else {
        intermediaria = (0);
        simbolo = ' ';
        strcpy(nomeoperacao, "erro");
    }
    
    
    printf("O simbolo da operação é %c e a %s entre %.2f e %.2f é igual a %.2f", simbolo,    nomeoperacao, numQuatro, numCinco, intermediaria);
    printf("\n---------------------- Fim operação matemática --------------------------");
    // Fim 6)


    // Inicio 7)
    printf("\n----------------------- Inicio pares de 0 a 100 ----------------------\n");
    int contador = 0;

    while (contador <= 100) {
        if (contador % 2 == 0) {
            printf("%i\n", contador);
            contador ++;
        }

        else {
            contador ++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n----------------------- Fim pares de 0 a 100 ----------------------\n");
    // Fim 7)


    // Inicio 8)
    printf("\n--------------------- Inicio fatorial ----------------------\n");
    int numero;
    
    printf("Digite um número para calcular o fatorial: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    
    int fatorial = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
        fatorial *= i;
    }
    
    printf("O fatorial de %d é: %d\n", numero, fatorial);
    
    return 0;
    printf("\n----------------------- Fim fatorial ------------------------\n");
    // Fim 8)


    // Inicio 9)
    printf("\n--------------------- Inicio maior número ----------------------\n");
    int numeroSeis, maior = 0;
    char continuar;

    do {
        printf("Digite um número inteiro: ");
        scanf("%hd", &numeroSeis);

        if (numeroSeis > maior) {
            maior = numeroSeis;
        }

        printf("Quer continuar? (s/n): ");
        scanf(" %c", &continuar);

    } while (continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');

    printf("O maior número digitado foi: %d\n", maior);

    return 0;
    printf("\n----------------------- Fim maior número ------------------------\n");
    // Fim 9)


    // Inicio 10)
    printf("\n------------------- Inicio sequência fibonacci -----------------------\n");
    int termos = 10;
    int primeiroTermo = 0, segundoTermo = 1;

    printf("Série de Fibonacci até o décimo termo:\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= termos; i++) {
        printf("%d ", primeiroTermo);
        int proximoTermo = primeiroTermo + segundoTermo;
        primeiroTermo = segundoTermo;
        segundoTermo = proximoTermo;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
    printf("\n------------------- Fim sequência fibonacci --------------------------\n");
    // Fim 10)
}
```

I removed some parts of the code and some times it work like the cpu or memory is full, but I had open the monitor and it's not true, in all compile it's enough, I closed all the programs and try again.

Comment: You have three unconditional `return 0` statements scattered across function `main`. Yes, those will cause a big part of function `main` to be optimized away by the compiler. Were you expecting anything else from those statements?

Comment: `compile` is the step that creates an executable from your source code. It would appear that is fine and you have a `runtime` issue

Comment: Stack Overflow has a portuguese language oriented site at https://pt.stackoverflow.com/  but you may get more help with this type of questions at forums like the one at htttp://clubedohardware.com.br

Comment: try each program in separate files. Whein you join all code understand that `return` in `main` means game over: the program ends. Your compiler warned you about unreachable code after `return`  statement

Comment: Since you have multiple unconditional `return` statements in your `main()` function all the code after the first `return 0` will never run. That might be an honest mistake or it may indicate you don't really understand even the most basic aspects of the C language and therefore should spend a little more time learning the language. Also, any good compiler will have given you a clear warning about the problem.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%hd", &numeroSeis);` has incorrect format specifier, so `int numeroSeis` won't be properly initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the error that I could detect:

- line 183: scanf("%hd", &numeroSeis) must be scanf("%d", &numeroSeis)
- line 179: char continuar must be something like char continuar = '\0'

some variables some times get initialized with random values and that may cause problem

- your code stop because in line 196
  because you used the return keyword with 0
  this mean your program exit with code 0

here is update to your code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
// Inicio 1
printf("\n----------------------- Inicio leitura de inteiro -------\n");
int num;

printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
scanf("%i", &num);

printf("O numero digitado é %i", num);
printf("\n----------------------- Fim leitura de inteiro ----------------------\n");
// Fim 1)


// Inicio 2)
printf("\n----------------------- Inicio soma ----------------------\n");
int numUm;
int numDois;

printf("Digite um numero inteiro para a soma: ");
scanf("%i", &numUm);
printf("Digite um segundo numero inteiro para a soma: ");
scanf("%i", &numDois);

int soma = numUm + numDois;

printf("A soma dos numero é igual a %i", soma);
printf("\n----------------------- Fim soma ----------------------\n");
// Fim 2)


// Inicio 3)
printf("\n----------------------- Inicio calculo de area ----------------------\n");
float raio;

printf("Digite o raio: ");
scanf("%f", &raio);

float area = ((raio * raio) * 3.1416);

printf("Considerando pi = 3,1416, a area da circunferência é %.2f", area);
printf("\n----------------------- Fim calculo de area ----------------------\n");
// Fim 3)


// Inicio 4)
printf("\n-------------------- Inicio conversor de temperatura ------------------\n");
float celsius;

printf("Digite a temperatura em Cº: ");
scanf("%f", &celsius);

float fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9/5) + 32);

printf("%.2fº celsius é equivalente a %.2f fahrenheits", celsius, fahrenheit);
printf("\n--------------------- Fim conversor de temperatura -------------------\n");
// Fim 4)


// Inicio 5)
printf("\n-------------------- Inicio positivo, negativo, 0 --------------------\n");
int numTres;

printf("Digite um número inteiro: ");
scanf("%i", &numTres);

if (numTres > 0) {
    printf("O numero %i é positivo.", numTres);
}

else if (numTres < 0) {
    printf("O numero %i é negativo", numTres);
}

else if (numTres == 0) {
    printf("O numero é igual a 0");
}
printf("\n---------------------- Fim positivo, negativo, 0 ----------------------\n");
// Fim 5)


// Inicio 6)
char nomeoperacao[20], simbolo = ' ';
int escolha;
float numQuatro, numCinco, intermediaria;

printf("\n------------------------ Operação matemática ----------------------------");
printf("\n 1- soma \n 2- subtração \n 3- multiplicação \n 4- Divisão\n");
printf("Opção desejada: ");
scanf("%i", &escolha);

printf("\nDigite um número para operação: ");
scanf("%f", &numQuatro);
printf("\nDigite um segundo número para operação: ");
scanf("%f", &numCinco);

if (escolha == 1) {
    intermediaria = (numQuatro + numCinco);
    simbolo = '+';
    strcpy(nomeoperacao, "soma");
}

else if (escolha == 2) {
    intermediaria = (numQuatro - numCinco);
    simbolo = '-';
    strcpy(nomeoperacao, "subtração");
}

else if (escolha == 3) {
    intermediaria = (numQuatro * numCinco);
    simbolo = '*';
    strcpy(nomeoperacao, "multiplicação");    
}

else if (escolha == 4) {
    intermediaria = (numQuatro / numCinco);
    simbolo = '/';
    strcpy(nomeoperacao, "divisão");    
}

else {
    intermediaria = (0);
    simbolo = ' ';
    strcpy(nomeoperacao, "erro");
}


printf("O simbolo da operação é %c e a %s entre %.2f e %.2f é igual a %.2f", simbolo,    nomeoperacao, numQuatro, numCinco, intermediaria);
printf("\n---------------------- Fim operação matemática --------------------------");
// Fim 6)


// Inicio 7)
printf("\n----------------------- Inicio pares de 0 a 100 ----------------------\n");
int contador = 0;

while (contador <= 100) {
    if (contador % 2 == 0) {
        printf("%i\n", contador);
        contador ++;
    }

    else {
        contador ++;
    }
}
printf("\n----------------------- Fim pares de 0 a 100 ----------------------\n");
// Fim 7)


// Inicio 8)
printf("\n--------------------- Inicio fatorial ----------------------\n");
int numero;

printf("Digite um número para calcular o fatorial: ");
scanf("%d", &numero);

int fatorial = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
    fatorial *= i;
}

printf("O fatorial de %d é: %d\n", numero, fatorial);

printf("\n----------------------- Fim fatorial ------------------------\n");
// Fim 8)

// Inicio 9)
printf("\n--------------------- Inicio maior número ----------------------\n");
int numeroSeis, maior = 0;
char continuar;

do {
    printf("Digite um número inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &numeroSeis);

    if (numeroSeis > maior) {
        maior = numeroSeis;
    }

    printf("Quer continuar? (s/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &continuar);

} while (continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');

printf("O maior número digitado foi: %d\n", maior);

printf("\n----------------------- Fim maior número ------------------------\n");
// Fim 9)

// Inicio 10)
printf("\n------------------- Inicio sequência fibonacci -----------------------\n");
int termos = 10;
int primeiroTermo = 0, segundoTermo = 1;

printf("Série de Fibonacci até o décimo termo:\n");

for (int i = 1; i <= termos; i++) {
    printf("%d ", primeiroTermo);
    int proximoTermo = primeiroTermo + segundoTermo;
    primeiroTermo = segundoTermo;
    segundoTermo = proximoTermo;
}

printf("\n");

printf("\n------------------- Fim sequência fibonacci --------------------------\n");
// Fim 10)
```